# Error when shutting down tomcat server

Tags: debugging, tomcat, remote-debugging, catalina, java-opts

I had started tomcat in debug mode by setting the java_opts. It worked I was able to debug using IntelliJ.

However, when I try to stop tomcat using

./catalina stop

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use ERROR:
>   JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
>   JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports
>   initialized [debugInit.c:750] FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No
>   transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answear when I searched further.
Basically, instead of JAVA_OPTS, using CATALINA_OPTS, solved this issue.

I found this answear in the following here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8216921/1720969